# Can't set folder permission on volume with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, volumes, mounted-volumes

I need to mount a folder inside a docker container with specific permission for the folder and the files inside it (700 for the folder and 600 for the files).
It is not enough to mount the folder with the 'rw directly under the service section since some programs specifically require permission to be 700 and 600.

Now I am trying to declare the volumes in docker-compose.yml as follows, but it gives me an error when turning up the container.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        volumes:
            - 'ssh-credentials:/root/.ssh'
volumes:
    ssh-credentials:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            o: bind,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0600
            type: none
            device: ./.ssh
```

The error returned is the following:
`Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/example-app_ssh-credentials/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount ./.ssh:/var/lib/docker/volumes/example-app_ssh-credentials/_data, flags: 0x1000, data: dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0600: no such file or directory`

Comment: have you checked whether .ssh directory of the user you use already exists inside the container?

Comment: yes, the directory does not exist before mounting the volume.